# Scaling layout background referring other layout background

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout, layout

[image]

Hi guys, I have a question. I have two linear layout. linearLayout1 with orange_dot.9.png background, and linearLayout2 with rectangle_white.9.png background. I put the textView inside of linearLayout2. My question, is there any ways how the linearLayout1 scaling fits as linearLayout2 so linearLayout1 have the same height with linearLayout2 ?

Here is what my xml layout looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/icon_status" 
        layout="@layout/layout_icon_status"/>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/relative_booking_item"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_status"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:background="@drawable/img_white_container">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/text_title"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
           android:text="gdsgdsgdsgsdgsgdsgdgsgdsgdsgdsgsdgsdgsgdsg"
           android:textColor="#FFF59120"
           android:textSize="15sp"
           android:paddingLeft="8dp"
           android:paddingRight="8dp"
           android:paddingTop="8dp"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

Use the following properties in your linearLayout1

```
android:alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by android weight property.

```
//Parent layout
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

//Child layout
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
>
//content
</LinearLayout>

//Child layout 2
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1">

//content
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```